How to reverse the tokenizer.apply_chat_template() method and handle streaming responses in Hugging Face?
While working with streaming, I found that it's not possible to use pipeline (at least we need HuggingFacePipeline and langchain, if I'm wrong let me know)
I'm looking for a way to extract assistant response from the streaming result without any special token, how can I do that?
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import TextStreamer
import torch

# Model and tokenizer initialization
model_id = "google/gemma-2b-it"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = model.to('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Chat template example
chat = [
    { "role": "user", "content": "Random prompt."},
]

# Applying chat template
question = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(chat, tokenize=False, add_generation_prompt=True)

# Tokenizing the question
question_tokenized = tokenizer(question, return_tensors="pt").to(model.device)

# Streamer setup
streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=True)
_ = model.generate(**question, streamer=streamer,
                            pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id, 
                            max_length=2048, 
                            temperature=0,
                            top_p=0.8,
                            repetition_penalty=1.25)

